# Have averages, need variance

Tags: statistics, average, standard-deviation

I have a large spreadsheet, generated by a colleague, that contains the results of $E$ experiments. For each experiment, he calculated the average of $M$ measurements.

I need the calculate the average and variance of all measurements, but due to the complex structure of the spreadsheet, I cannot make the calculation directly in the spreadsheet, nor copy the data to another spreadsheet. How can use the current data, i.e., the averages per experiment and the number of measurements per experiment, to calculate the average and variance of all measurements?

Here is what I did so far. Let $x_{ij}$ be measurement $j$ in experiment $i$.

Let $a_i$ be the average of experiment $i$:

$$a_i = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^{M}{ x_{ij} } $$

Let $A$ be the total average:

$$A = \frac{1}{EM} \sum_{i=1}^{E}{ \sum_{j=1}^{M}{ x_{ij} } } = \frac{1}{E} \sum_{i=1}^E {a_i}$$

So, I CAN calculate the total average by averaging the averages per experiment $a_i$.

However, this trick doesn't seem to work for the variance. I need to calculate $V$:

$$V = \frac{1}{EM} \sum_{i=1}^{E}{ \sum_{j=1}^{M}{ (x_{ij} - A)^2 } }$$

But if I calculate the variance of the $a_i$'s, I get:

$$V' = \frac{1}{E} \sum_{i=1}^{E}{ (a_{i} - A)^2 }$$

These don't seem similar:

$$V - V' 
  = \frac{1}{EM} \sum_{i=1}^{E}{ 
   \sum_{j=1}^{M}{ [(x_{ij} - A)^2  
   - (a_{i} - A)^2]
  } }$$
$$  = \frac{1}{EM} \sum_{i=1}^{E}{ 
   \sum_{j=1}^{M}{ [(x_{ij} + a_{i} - 2A)\cdot(x_{ij}-a_{i})]
  } }
$$

Can I use the existing data to get, at least, an approximation to $V$?

Comment: I am afraid an exact evaluation may be impossible given only the given data

Comment: Is there anything else known about the data (e.g., its distribution) that might let you relate the variance of the averages to the variance of the measurements?

Comment: I'd suggest writing out the difference between $V$ and $V'$ and seeing if there is a way to minimize it. For instance, if you can pick and choose which data sets you use, maybe you could affect the error by maximizing $E$ and minimizing $M$. Just a thought.

Comment: Just to double check your constraints, you can't even calculate the sum of squares $\sum_{j=1}^M x_{ij}^2$ for each experiment and aggregate those in a similar way to the way that you aggregate the $a_i$s? Sorry if this is a silly question but it's worth being sure.

Comment: If you keep the sum (or average) of the $x_i^2$ for each run, then you can compute the sum of all the squares over all runs, and therefore compute the sample standard deviation.